# How to fix errors when installing Jupyter to my Linux VM

Tags: software-installation, virtual-machine, pip

I'm having trouble installing Jupyter notebook into my Linux virtual machine. Every time I use anything with `pip` or `pip3` in it (e.g. `sudo python3 -m pip install jupyter`), I get this error (or a very similar error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone please help me understand what the error means, and how I could go about fixing it to install Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

You have incompatible versions of Python and pip installed -- pip >= 21.0 [requires Python 3.6 or newer](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/9189). The traceback shows pip is using [fstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), feature that was added in Python 3.6. I see you installed Pip manually (it's located in your home directory) so you either need to install older version with pip or upgrade your Python version.

I would recommend using system version of pip (package `python3-pip` on most distributions) to make sure to have compatible version of Python and pip. Or use Python [virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) if you need specific Python version for development.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I tried uninstalling all python versions & then reinstalling specifically only Python3.7 (also uninstalled pip & reinstalled only the latest version), but I'm still getting the same errors. I double checked the list of all Python versions installed & every version is still there. I think these are the defaults of the VM, as I didn't install these myself. So I tried making a virtual env. to only work with 1 version of Python, but in order to install virtualenv, I need pip3, which gives me the error above. I'm stuck in an error loop, do you have any suggestions?